# Get data with publish unpublish date using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have pubish and unpublish date for news. Now I want to dynamically select all news whose current date lies in between publish date and unpublish date.

I have description, publish_date and unpublish_date as table columns.

Do I have to do mysql union or is there some other simple ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for the between operator:

```
WHERE 'current date' BETWEEN publish_date AND unpublish_date
```

This only works if your publish_date and unpublish_date are of type date!
In case you are using TEXT or VARCHAR as column type you could use:

```
TO_DATE(publish_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

To convert from Text to date with specified format